# При вставке видео с YouTube идет долгая загрузка сайта

Tags: javascript, html, веб-сайт

Само видео загружается быстро и хорошо. Проблем нет. Ах да, загружаю я видео встраивая в iframe. Но вот есть проблема с тем, что сам сайт после того как открылся, еще крутится вот там где favicon, будто сайт еще подгружается. Хотя все уже загрузилось. Это ладно, но сайт еще и подтормаживает из-за этого.
Я подозреваю, это из-за того, что на ютубе же не загружаются аватарки каналов.
Может кто-то знает как можно это починить?